# Caliburn.Micro No target found for method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro for my WP7 project and I keep getting this strange error for some of my pages. I can't reproduce it myself but it very often appears in Bugsense logs. This is how I use it. 
XAML:

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded] = [Action Init()]"
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
public async Task Init() {...}
```

Or on other pages just

```
public void Init() {...}
```

This is stacktrace from Bugsense:

```
0 System.Exception: No target found for method Init.
1 at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.Invoke(Object eventArgs)
2 at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction.CallInvoke(Object parameter)
3 at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(Object parameter)
4 at System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs)
5 at System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEventImpl(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
6 at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
7 at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Any ideas on how I can determine what's wrong?

Comment: so you use void Init() to fire Task Init()?

Comment: no, I use `void Init()` to do some simple post-load actions on some pages, but on the other pages when I need to use some async features like getting string from webservice I use `Task Init()` signature

Comment: that might be your issue, Message.Attach will call Init() on the VM if the signature matches (usually means ```public void```), as for the page however unless you are using the Page's loaded event CM will not find Init() on the View.  if you are pulling the view into the VM that sort of breaks mvvm/testability.

Comment: The main problem here is that I can't reproduce this issue, it just appears in logs. What can be wrong if it fails only in about 1% of cases?

Comment: honestly I haven't the faintest idea other than it isn't finding context associated with the call, meaning what ever called the Init() might actually not have the associated signature in the ViewModel.